# How does Majora's Mask fit into the timeline?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask

I want to start the game on friday. After playing Ocarina of Time a long time ago I ask myself how MM fits into the timeline. Is it a direct sequel to OoT? I mean you start the game as a kid again and as far as I remember you were an adult at the end of OoT.

Comment: Aren't all Zelda games independant?

Comment: @BobR.Shake nope

Comment: @Ender I saw that :P

Comment: @BobR.Shake though knowing more about the connections isn't really necessary to play any of the games. "There have been lots of similar heroes in the past, and will probably be more in the future" is enough to get most of the references (green clothing being called "Hero's Clothes" in many games, for instance).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several "theories" about the timeline of the Zelda franchise, and all do make sense in their own ways. The interesting thing to note is that the timeline actually *splits* after Ocarina of Time.

Nintendo actually did release an official timeline for the Zelda franchise:
[image]

However, some believe that this is incorrect, and a different timeline has been created, though this is... just a game theory...

But to answer your question: *"Where does MM fit into the timeline?"* It *is* a direct sequel to OoT (by direct I mean it is *one* of the games that occurs *directly after* the events of OoT).

Comment: The video doesn't actually say the timeline is wrong, despite the clickbait-y title, it just plays semantics saying that it's not a time*line* because it splits.

Comment: @Michaellogg I should point out that it was just a *theory* created by someone the had another idea, for a bit of fun. As for the *actual* story line, it was created by Nintendo, so that every one will know the actual storyine.

Answer (score 5):

At the end of OoT, Link returned the titular Ocarina of Time to Princess Zelda. After that, Link is seen in front of the Master Sword stuck in the Pedestal of Time as a kid, which essentially means he's returned to the past. Navi leaves Link, and Link walks away from the sword.

You can skip to 8:54 to see the scene in question.

---

At the very beginning of Majora's Mask, we get to see a bit of backstory. It explains how Link became the Hero of Time, and how he's now looking for a friend he parted ways with *when he finally fulfilled his heroic destiny and took his place among legends*.

Since the game begins in the Lost Woods, it is likely the friend Link is looking for is Navi, who indeed left him behind at the Temple of Time after he has *finally fulfilled his heroic destiny*.

Answer (score -6):

I believe that Link dies at the beginning of MM. And in the next chronological game, Twilight Princess, you play as a descendant of the dead Link. The Hero's Shade in Twilight Princess is the dead Link from Majora's Mask.

Comment: There are [legit theories](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S1SVkysIRw) [[transcript](https://ahliqq.co/blog/game-theory-is-link-dead-in-majoras-mask.html)] about this, but... it is after all just a theory (and this site is about hard answers, not theories)

Comment: ... and rather than being dead, it seems more likely that our hero is instead experiencing grief.